# How to subtract lines, in reverse, only if greater than previous line

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I am working on a shell script that will read the lines of a file, in reverse.  I need it to subtract the previous line from the latter, but only if the latter is larger.  If it's smaller, then I just want the number on that line.

#### Example:

File contents:

```
100
200
300
100
300
```

Results should be:

```
200     # line 5 - line 4    
100     # line 4 (as it's < line 3) 
100
100
```

The code I was using simply to subtract the lines previously (without taking into account if value was >= was:

```
awk 'p{print $0-p}{p=$0}' inputfile > outputfile
```

I need to still do this, but only if value is greater than previous line.

I was thinking of using a while read loop, but assigning a variable to each line for comparison, or something similar, is really taxing my brain.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tac` is useful to reverse the line order of a file - (also BSD `tail -r` can reverse the line order)

```
tac file | awk 'p { if( p>$1 ) print p-$1; else print p } { p=$1 }'
```

If, for some reason, you can't use `tac` or want to use awk exclusively, you can use `awk` to read the entire file into memory via an array, and `END{}` process the array in reverse order.

```
awk '{ r[i++]=$0};  END{ for(i=i-1; i>=0; i--) 
       if( r[i+1] ) if( r[i+1]>r[i] ) print r[i+1]-r[i]; else print r[i+1] 
     }' file
```

Comment: A more terse version for the `awk` part of your first solution can be `awk 'p{print (p>$0)?p-$0:p}{p=$0}'`.

Comment: Thanks!  I used the first one above "tac file | awk .....".  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tac` to reverse file and then `awk` for calculation. I've modified your `file` to make lines more random.

```
$ cat file
101
220
303
140
305
$ tac file | awk '{if(last>$0)print last-$0;else print last;last=$0}END{print last}'

165
140
83
119
101
```

Two remarks:

- After all you need to remove first line (empty line) if you don't
  need it.
- In the `END{}` block the very first line from the file is printed, remove this block if you don't want that.